# Facebook SDK 4.0 LoginButton - setReadPermissions is not working?

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I implemented the **LoginButton** from the Facebook 4.0 SDK. Login and Logout is working fine.

Now i want to set the "user_friends" permission with `LoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends"));`

But it seems, this line of code is ignored? 
When i read the permissions after successfully logged in with `getAccessToken().getPermissions();` i only have the **"basic_info"** permission.

If i use `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(    HighscoreFragment.this, Arrays.asList("user_friends") );` instead, i get the right permissions. But i want to use the **LoginButton**.

So what is the correct way to implement the **LoginButton** and set the needed permissions when logging in?

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_highscore, container, false);

        mLoginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        mLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends"));
        mLoginButton.setFragment(this);    

        // Callback registration
        mLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                Log.i(TAG, "LOGIN SUCCESFUL");
                Log.i(TAG, loginResult.getAccessToken().getPermissions().toString());
                AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                if (accessToken != null) {
                    if(accessToken.getPermissions().contains("user_friends"))
                        fetchScoreboardEntries();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i(TAG, "LOGIN CANCEL");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Log.i(TAG, "LOGIN ERROR");
            }
        });
```

Comment: this link doesn´t help in any way. It´s about **share dialog** with facebook sdk! Did you read my question?

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is thus:

1. You started with a bare LoginButton (only asks for `basic_info` permission)
2. You tested login and got a valid access token
3. You changed your code to ask for `user_friends` with the LoginButton
4. Now you can't get additional permissions with the LoginButton

I've identified this as a bug in the SDK, and we'll fix it in an upcoming release.

The current work around while you're in development is to de-authorize your app (from your Facebook settings) when you make LoginButton changes. That way, it will invalidate your access token, and the next time you log in, you should see `user_friends` in the permissions dialog. This should only be an issue if you're making changes to the permissions array in between app updates.